# Google Sheets, Import data from multiple sources into one, and create new tables

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, datatables

[The source data that i want to import, its on a different multiple worksheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS0vZ.png)
This image contains all the data that i want to send to the main table,
[Two of the tables are filled in manually, i want to do the third one using a script entirely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNU52.png)

I've already figured out how to write data from one sheet to another using this code:

```
function getdata() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
      
      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet name");;
      var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A:A');
      var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
      
    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('Sheet name'); 
    var destrange = destsheet.getRange('B:B'); 
    destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);         
 }
 }
```

---

Issue is with this is that it doesn't create new rows for new data, and it doesnt take into account when a new sheet is created.
I'm a lil confused, im new to javascript and im just the IT guy, but im willing to learn!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foEhO.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your 2 sample images, your script and your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being more detailed with my question, im new :-). The first [1] sample image contains the table information that I need to import into the second image[2]. Id like to do this with a button or just running the script. would that be possible? if theres anything else you wish to know, please ask.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic for achieving `The first [1] sample image contains the table information that I need to import into the second image[2].`. I apologize for this. About `Id like to do this with a button or just running the script. would that be possible?`, I think that it can be achieved.

Comment: Hey, i've edited in an illustrated version of my idea its the example link, maybe it explains itself better. English isn't my first language either so im pretty bad myself

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Dont worry about it! so to tear my question down to basics - I need to copy data from one sheet to another. And also create new space for that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Looks like you want to use the `copyTo()` method of the `Range` class.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation:

> `copyTo(destination)`
>
> Copies the data from a range of cells to another range of cells. Both the values and formatting are copied.
>
> ```
> // The code below copies the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
> var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
> var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 5);
> rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 6));
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
> | Name | Type | Description |
> |------|------|-------------|
> |`destination` | [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#) | A destination range to copy to; only the top-left cell position is relevant.|
> **Authorization**
>
> Scripts that use this method require authorization with one or more of the following [scopes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes):
>
> - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`
> - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

#### Working Example:

Using a script such as the following:

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C6:D20").copyTo(
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("E6:F20")
  )
}
```

You can copy data from one range to another while preserving properties such as text decoration:

[image]

#### References:

- [Class Range - copyTo(Range) | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))